# Update with Server time For Spring Mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mongodb

How to update entity with Mongo server time

```
Query query = new Query(new Criteria("id").is(user.getId()));
Update update = new Update().set("text", text)
    .set("timeStamp", ??? );
```

This field should only be updated in one method

*@LastModifiedDate* It does not suit me?

timeStamp is LocalDateTime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want either `.currentDate()` or `.currentTimestamp()` depending on your intended storage result.

```
Update update = new Update().set("text", text)
    .currentDate("timeStamp");
```

Which actually corresponds to the [`$currentDate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/) BSON update modifier and all the same usage, being of `{ $type: "date" }` or `{ $type: "timestamp" }` in it's options for the respective methods.

These are BSON Date values and therefore UTC Time.

Get the idea of Local time out of your head, since it has no business being stored in a database which can be accessed around the world.